# simple ajax request with interval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I recently began learning Ajax and jQuery. So yesterday I started to programm a simple ajax request for a formular, that sends a select list value to a php script and reads something out of a database.

It works so far! 
But the problem is, that when I click on the send button, it starts the request, 1 second later. I know that it has something to do with my interval. When I click on the send button, I start the request and every second it requests it also, so that I have the opportunity, to auto-refresh new income entries.

But I'd like to have that interval cycle every second, but the first time I press the button it should load immediately, not just 1 second later.

Here is my code:
http://jsbin.com/qitojawuva/1/edit

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var interval = 0;
    $("#form1").submit(function () {

        if (interval === 0) {
            interval = setInterval(function () {


                var url = "tbladen.php";
                var data = $("#form1").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#tbladen").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
        return false;
    });


});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: Also, note that `setTimeout` is better suited for Ajax polling than `setInterval` which cannot properly handle situations where the request takes more time than the interval itself.

Comment: @D4V1D, I think you meant `setTimeout` is better than `setInterval` when using ajax. Good point. `setTimeout` should be called only upon the ajax call's completion.

Comment: @KJPrice Yeah, got messed up when writing my comment. I've edited it properly.

Comment: `setTimeout` in your `ajax` callback is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I might be something like the following you're looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var isFirstTime = true;

    function sendForm() {
        var url = "tbladen.php";
        var data = $("#form1").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#tbladen").html(data);
            }
        });

    }

    $("#form1").submit(function () {

        if (isFirstTime) {
            sendForm();
            isFirstTime = false;
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                sendForm();
            }, 1000);
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, use `setTimeout` when the callback has finished as `setInterval` just keeps running whether or not your callback has finished.

```
$(function () {

    $("#form1").submit(postData);

    function postData() {
        var url = "tbladen.php",
            data = $("#form1").serialize();        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#tbladen").html(data);
                setTimeout(postData, 1000);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Kind of [related demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/3e3bb3jj/)

Comment: Thanks, your version works :). but one thing: How can I avoid to adding up new request by pressing the submit button mutliple times in your version? Because in my basic version I used "if (interval === 0){....}" to avoid it, that I won't flood the server. I tried to find a way to use it in your code too, but my results were just, that it stopped overall and didn't refresh anymore.

Comment: Disable the submit button once pressed, like [http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/3e3bb3jj/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/3e3bb3jj/2/)